# How to remove broken background of ListViewItem In UWP?

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

[image]

I Created a Listview with some items.
When I click at one, I'm navigating to new page.
When I press back, l'm going back to the old page (Main menu page -> item page -> backing to main menu by Frame.GoBack()) and
I see all last clicked items are having gray background.
I tried to set background to transparent, it doesn't work.

**On Desktop this problem doesn't exist, Background is black.**
I'm testing it at Windows 10 RS2 & Windows 10 Mobile last insider build at L640XL.

Listview:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="
          Name="LineSecondTrackListView"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind _LineSecondTrackBusStops}"
          ContainerContentChanging="SetBusStopViewAttribute"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BusStopListViewStyle}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionChanged="LineTrackListView_SelectionChangedAsync">
              <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                      <ItemsWrapGrid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                     Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                     MaximumRowsOrColumns="1"/>
                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
              </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

How i'm backing:

```
public static void BackButtonPressed(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame mainAppFrame = MainFrameHelper.GetMainFrame();
    Type currentPageType = mainAppFrame.CurrentSourcePageType;
    bool goBack = IsGoBackFromPageAllowed(currentPageType);
    if (goBack)
    {
        mainAppFrame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    App.Current.Exit();
}

private static bool IsGoBackFromPageAllowed(Type currentPageType)
{
    if (currentPageType == typeof(Pages.Lines.LinesViewPage))
        return true;
    if (currentPageType == typeof(Pages.Lines.LinePage))
        return true;
    if (currentPageType == typeof(Pages.Lines.LineBusStopPage))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

How to avoid this effect?

**Edit**

I tried with

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in LineSecondTrackListView.Items) 
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(item, "Normal", false); //in the OnNavigatedTo
```

and it doesnt work

**edit2**
In main menu page, when I clicked at button and went back, this effect stays. All pages are having `NavigationCachePage=Required`
[image: main menu]

**edit3**

```
ButtonListGridView.InvalidateMeasure();
ButtonListGridView.UpdateLayout();
ButtonListGridView.InvalidateArrange();
```

any of these did not fix that.

Comment: Try use Background = #00FFFFFF

Comment: Are you caching the page using NavigationCacheMode.Enabled or NavigationCacheMode.Required? I'm hitting the same issue in my app but haven't find any solution. :/

Comment: Maybe using foreach (ListViewItem item in LineSecondTrackListView.Items) VisualStateManager.GoToState(item, "Normal", false); in the OnNavigatedTo method override could help. (Not tested, I got this idea a few minutes ago.)

Comment: Does it happen on the non-insider SDK?

Comment: Im in school now so i can't check for background #00FFFFFF. Im using .Required. | Yes. on non-insider SDK this is happening too. ( I checked it before )

Comment: I not think my way is explicit to solve it.

Comment: Try NavigationCacheMode.Disabled

Comment: I cant set to disabled because this page takes too much resources and is loading in a few seconds on phone.

Comment: @MarianDolinský Setting state to "normal" not working.

Comment: Have you tried to call *UpdateLayout()* or *Invalidate* on the *ListView*? As a workaround, maybe reassigning the collection to *ItemsSource* will work.

Comment: @Romasz I Tried with UpdateLayout(). This was what i firstly did. I think that setting new ItemSource will be workaround, but I want to know what is causing this problem. //pol: Swoją drogą mam wrażenie, ze to coś przez NavigationCacheMode

Comment: I'm not sure what is the source of the problem, seems to be something with VisualStates of items and cached values. I've already seen some weird behaviors of other controls, strange artifacts and so on, some of them got fixed and some needed a workaround. (Don't add Polish comments/posts - this is English-only site and it would be a mess if everybody started to talk in their own language).

Comment: @Romasz so for now the workaround is as you said, refeshing ItemSource. I will still wait. Maybe someone had similar problem and fixed it.

Comment: can you post how the BusStopListViewStyle looks like?

Comment: @RTDev https://github.com/gtteamamxx/Rozklad-Jazdy-v2/blob/a00b325e59a64cedd6c39deefc7c8bc5e4e97c74/Rozk%C5%82adJazdyv2/Pages/Lines/LinePage.xaml

Here you have all code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things you can try here. I believe the *gray background* you see is the `PressedBackground` of the `ListViewItemPresenter`.

It's most likely a timing bug in UWP that when an item in the `ListView` is selected/pressed down, the `PressedBackground`/`PointerOverBackground` shows, and at the same time the *page 1* is being cached and cleared from the `Frame` which can then display *page 2*, but what should happen before caching is that the *page 1* needs to complete the **pointer up/exit action** in order to clear the `PressedBackground`/`PointerOverBackground` color, which it fails to do so.

To test out if that's the color of the issue, all you need is to apply the following default `Style` to your the `ItemContainerStyle` of your `ListView`, and set `PressedBackground="Transparent"` or/and `PointerOverBackground="Transparent"`.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
<Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
<Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <ListViewItemPresenter
          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
          SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
          CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
          CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
          DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
          FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
          FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
          PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          PointerOverBackground="Transparent"
          PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
          SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
          SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
          SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
          PressedBackground="Transparent"
          SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
          DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
          DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
          ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
          ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
          CheckMode="Inline"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

But even this might fix the issue, it removes a meaningful visual indication. So let's try something else -

In your `LineTrackListView_SelectionChangedAsync` method, instead of navigating right after the delay, you de-select the item first, give it the same amount of delay to complete the de-selecting action, and then do the navigation. You will need to have a flag to avoid this method to be re-called by updating the `SelectedItem`.

```
private bool _isWorking;

private async void LineTrackListView_SelectionChangedAsync(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isWorking)
    {
        return;
    }

    _isWorking = true;

    // Removed some of your code here.

    listView.SelectedItem = -1;
    await Task.Delay(100);

    ChangePageToBusPage(selectedBusStopInListView.BusStop, selectedTrack);

    _isWorking = false;
}
```

I don't have a Windows Phone so I can't really test the code but hopefully it will give you an idea. Good luck!

Comment: What works? 

Working with style doesnt worked for me, but i had to add before changing page resetting selected item. And... changing Task.Delay from 100 to 250.
Thanks a lot, and happy codding :)

Answer (score 0):

In your list view handle the onclick/onselect events and set the item to Unselected.

Comment: I want all selected Items left as selected